# Winlogon\Notify Registry Key

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, winlogon.exe

If I delete/modify the HKLM\SOFTWARE\MicrosoftWindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Notify registry key, will this disable Winlogon events from being past to the event log?  The Windows Dev Center entry is a bit unclear about the interaction:

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/winlogon-notification-packages

Comment: screenshot of the popup would be nice.

Comment: @Moab I have reworded the question as the greater context was creating confusion.